# Sqlite database and swipe to delete

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, tableview, sql-delete

The project I'm working on required me to use a sqlite database, and I've been trying to get swipe to delete to work on my tableView:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(removeMovieFromCache:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:movieId] waitUntilDone:YES];
    [db performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(performQuery:) withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM movie WHERE id = %d", movieId] waitUntilDone:YES];
    [db performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(performQuery:) withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM new_movies WHERE new_movie_id = %d", movieId] waitUntilDone:YES];
    [self removeMovieFromCache:movieId];
    [db performQueryWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM movie WHERE id = %d", movieId];
    [db performQueryWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM new_movies WHERE new_movie_id = %d", movieId];
    [db performQuery:@"COMMIT"];
```

That's the code to get rid of something from my database. When I try to apply this to  my swipe to delete command of:

```
-

(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)movieID
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {        

      //code goes here        
    }
}
```

It just doesn't want to work, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: i have but not in that style of: "tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:" i've used "-

(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath" ect  but i haven't got the last to, how should i implement them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your tableView Data Source, try implementing this:

```
(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath 
{
   return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}


(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
   return YES;
}

(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)movieID
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {       
       // First delete the row from the table, then delete from the DB, finally reload the date in the table 
       [theTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
       // code to delete from DB
       [theTable reloadData];        
    }
}
```

(replace "theTable" with whatever you've called your table!)